# Why two svnrdump are different on the same revision of the repro?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

when I run the same svndump command twice, on a repro with the same revision,the dumps are not the same on the diff.

```
svnrdump dump http://example.com/svn/repo1 > repo1.svndump
```

How do I turn it off?

Here a example of the differences[image: example of the differences]

Comment: I don't think the svnrdump command has an "add random differences to the dump" flag you can disable. Would you mind explaining what differences you're finding and why they're an issue?

Comment: i just ran the above command twice and compared the result by diff. see the screenshot as well

Comment: Do you need further help to answer the second part of my question? It's hard to see what the actual differences are in that hex dump but it seems files are listed in a different order. What's breaking as a consequence of that? Are you trying to determine if there've been further commits?